# Array values retrieving not working

Tags: php, html, arrays, file, input

I've an input field where I paste an url and I want to fetch the details from an url, After fetching the result now I'm unable to assign these values to an input filed. You can see the link [here](http://edesignary.com/scrap/index.php)

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="ref_url" placeholder="Paste the URL" value="https://www.lovely-cards.com/wedding-cards/1836-ethnica01.html">
    <input type="submit" value="Get Details">
</form>

<input type="text" name="height" value="<?php echo $tags[0]['height']; ?>">
```

PHP

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');

if (!EMPTY(isset($_POST['ref_url']))) {
    $url = $_POST['ref_url'];
    $html = file_get_html($url);
    $row = $html->find('tr');
    unset($row[0]);
    unset($row[1]);
    foreach($row as $element) {
        $tag_name = $element->find('td',0)->plaintext;
        $tag_value = $element->find('td',1)->plaintext;
        if (!EMPTY($tag_name) && !EMPTY($tag_value)) {
        $tags[] = array($tag_name =>$tag_value);        
        }
    }
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($tags);
    echo '</pre>';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its 'Height' not 'height' which you are trying to set to